# How to find unique combinations for a table column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've below table: Test

```
create table test (Id char)

insert into test values
('A'),
('B'),
('C'),
('D'),
('E')
```

[Fiddle Link for testing](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=09723c27d37ac9190754b5b795d3714b)

Expected Output:

1. a.ID   b.ID

- A      B
- A      C
- A      D
- A      E
- B      C
- B      D
- B      E
- C      D
- C      E
- D      E

I tried below code:

```
select a.id, b.id from test a cross join test b where a.id<>b.id
```

But my current output has invalid combination which are already present above refer image
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zra2j.jpg) (highlighted records are invalid as they are present above in inverse order)

Comment: CROSS JOIN and WHERE... Do INNER JOIN instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be fairly simple; switch from `<>` to `<`:

```
select a.id, b.id from test a cross join test b where a.id < b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a hierarchical query to avoid a self-join:

```sql
SELECT id, PRIOR id AS id2
FROM   test
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR id > id
ORDER BY id, id2
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID | ID2
> :- | :--
> A  | B  
> A  | C  
> A  | D  
> A  | E  
> B  | C  
> B  | D  
> B  | E  
> C  | D  
> C  | E  
> D  | E
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e16c42b4a32261d307d9be31a54d2c5)*